# "Waiting for the host to start the meeting" from the host side while using flutter_zoom_sdk plugin

Tags: android, ios, flutter, zoom-sdk

We are using Zoom API to create meetings from our server with a given date, and time. And I am getting the result data through API in the app. And then letting users and hosts join the meeting from the result data ***(i.e. meeting id and passcode)*** in the respective role.

But every time it's showing ***"Waiting for the host to start the meeting"*** even from the host side which is not letting the host in. I am passing the email used to create the meeting as userID to the flutter plugin. And using SDK app key and the secret to authenticate to zoom using [**flutter_zoom_sdk**](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_zoom_sdk), as per plugin doc. I am also not able to pass the role key as host as there is no use of the JWT token on the mobile side of the plugin.
But the official doc of the android SDK is saying something like [**this**](https://marketplace.zoom.us/docs/sdk/native-sdks/android/getting-started/enter-credentials).

Can anyone tell me the way to join an existing meeting as a host with a meeting id and passcode already created?